# Word's Equation Editor

Tags: ms-word, equation

I am trying to create an application that does what Microsoft Office Word's Equation editor does. Is there any resource or documentation available for this little tool? I have actually no idea where to start from, and this is what I need: a start point! Can anybody help me?

P.S. I have found this: [MathType](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/). But it is not an open-source application so I don't have anything to learn from it.

Comment: You might want to look at discussions of graphical editors on the TeX board. On the other hand, most TeX writers tend to avoid those.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean with "TeX board". Could you give me a link?:D

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ which is in the first column of this site's footer as TeX-LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to work via Microsoft's solutions, you have two choices.

1. Use word automation (or interop), make word do what you wish. You may want to look at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.omaths(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.omaths%28v=office.14%29.aspx) as a starting point. The best way to understand how to make something happen with automation is to start Word, record a macro ([http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/record-or-run-a-macro-HA010099769.aspx)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/record-or-run-a-macro-HA010099769.aspx) of something and then view the generated code. For example, inserting a new fraction will look something like this (in Vb.Net)

   Selection.OMaths(1).Functions.Add(Selection.Range, wdOMathFunctionFrac).Frac.Type = wdOMathFracBar
2. Another option is to work with the DOCX file directly. You could use the OpenXML SDK (http://openxmldeveloper.org/) to create whatever docx you wish. Like in the previous case, it is extremely difficult to understand how to do things by using the documentation. The sane way is to get the Productivity Tool (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124). This will allow you to open any office 2007+ document and see the code needed to generate it. Create whatever equation you wish, save it, open it with the productivity tool and see how it's done.

The openXML approach is much faster, it will allow you to multithread and does not require Office to be installed. The Interop is easier to start with (and understand) and gives you access to some of the logic that's inside Office - for example, you could create Table of Contents rather easily.

Enjoy.